# how to start graphical user interface mode in oracle linux 7.2

Tags: gui, oracle-linux

I have gone through oracle's documentation here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E54695/html/index.html but coundn't find a content where it states starting a gui in oracle linux. I have tried startx but it doesn't seem to work.

I also tried running. systemctl set-default graphical.target

at first run, it prompted that it create a symlink. assuming something was configured, I restarted my machine. But it still boots up in server mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/oracle-linux-7-installation)

It would be advisable to click on the "Software Selection" link and pick the following options if you want a GUI console.

```
Base Environment > Server with GUI
Add-Ons for Selected Environment > Compatibility Libraries
Add-Ons for Selected Environment > Development Tools
```

Once you have completed your selections, click the "Done" button.